# Drupal 8 field API vs. $form_state

Tags: entities, 8

I am creating a field with Field API, and having it shown on user registration form. However, I need its value in order to make validation. For that purpose, I've used `dpm($form_state)` which gave me the dreadful, dreadful memory exhaustion error. I then used `file_put_contents(' sites/default/files/debug.txt', print_r($form_state, TRUE));` which did not produce anything at all. I also tried a few suggestions made on IRC, among which are `$form_state->getValue(['field_tckn']). It seems I can't get what my field's value is, no matter what I do; and all I get is that the field is required when I fill it in; and I'm all out of ideas. Can you recommend anything else?

Comment: Try the devel module's dd() function.

Comment: You probably need to increase your memory limit in the site. $form_state is now a `FormState` object. https://www.drupal.org/node/2310411

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from http://www.drupal.org/node/2350819:

If you import a field, it automatically goes into the disabled section because the fact that a field is shown or not is now stored in the entity display config entities, which fields do not now anything off. I should check what our default behavior is, but this is probably by design - which makes sense actually. And if not, it'll be a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to inspect all values in $form_state with the getValues() function. I was able to successfully inspect with the following after also running into the Out of memory error:

```
dpm($form_state->getValues());
```

Comment: Hi, not only I get array(0) on user_form and nothing on user_profile form, I get `<myfield> field is required` even when I fill it in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a bug with the field system. I'll try again when it is fixed. The bug in question is http://www.drupal.org/node/2350819.